# Read from a CSV file and write each line into a Different File

Tags: java

My input CSV having data like-

```
    VBS123ER,Abc_123,TEST_REPORT_FOR_SA,15-JUN-2020,76854,SAMPLE_REPORT


    VBS123ER,Abc_123,TEST_REPORT_FOR_SA,15-JUN-2020,76855,SAMPLE_REPORT
```

I want to read each line from my CSV and create a New CSV/TXT file for each line.
Like- For row 1 one file will be created called 1.txt/1.csv which will be holding all row 1 data. Same for row 2 and so on..
How in java we can achieve this?

```
File f = new File("C:\\Test\\AR_POC\\Input.txt"); 
BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f)); 
String readLine = ""; 
System.out.println("Reading file using Buffered Reader"); 
while ((readLine = b.readLine()) != null) { 
    System.out.println(readLine); 
    for(int i = 0; i < readLine.length; i++) { 
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Test\\AR_POC\\" + Name + i + ".txt"); 
        fo.write(readLine.getBytes()); 
        fo.close(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: let us know what you have tried

Comment: File f = new File("C:\\Test\\AR_POC\\Input.txt");
   BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
   String readLine = "";

            System.out.println("Reading file using Buffered Reader");

            while ((readLine = b.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(readLine);
                for(int i=0; i<readLine.length; i++){
                FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Test\\AR_POC\\" + Name + i + ".txt");
                fo.write(readLine.getBytes());
                fo.close();
                }

Comment: add the code to the question, and let us know what issue you are facing

Comment: It's taking length of the first row and keep on creating txt file with 1st row data till the length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should count the lines in the input file, not the length of current line:

```
File f = new File("C:\\Test\\AR_POC\\Input.txt"); 
BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f)); 
String readLine = ""; 
System.out.println("Reading file using Buffered Reader");
int i = 0;
while ((readLine = b.readLine()) != null) { 
    System.out.println(readLine);
    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Test\\AR_POC\\" + Name + i++ + ".txt"); 
    fo.write(readLine.getBytes()); 
    fo.close(); 
}
```